# What does CC699 mean in reference to Plutonium?

Tags: radioactivity

[image]

I noticed that Plutonium storage containers often have cc699 written on them.

A Google search for cc699 also brings up plutonium as the first page but I can't find any mention of cc699 on the page or anywhere else online.

What is the connection between cc699 and Plutonium?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a movie, not physics.

Comment: Re your edit (v2): movie props have a different set of labelling requirements than nuclear materials --- especially accountable nuclear materials. Removing the context that you saw this label on a movie prop, rather than laboratory in a particular country, makes your question harder to answer, not easier.